# Walking directories

Tags: python, directory-walk

I am searching for a specific directory (/android).

I know that in python I can walk directories with os.walk(root_dir) but the problem here is that I do not know if the directory that I am looking for is a child of root_dir or if its a parent directory of root_dir.

Is there any method that perform the same operation than os.walk() but in the opposite way?

Thanks.

Comment: You can change the current working directory upwards using `os.chdir('..')`, amongst other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to parent directory of `root_dir` by using `..` in `os.path.abspath()`.

```
import os
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root_dir, ".."))
```

Now you have `parent_directory` of `root_dir` in `parent_dir`, You can make it `root_dir` and use `os.walk(root_dir)` again.

Comment: That adds a lot of complexity to the code what if I am dealing with a lot of directories, I will at each attemps walk all the tree if I don't find the directory I am looking for I just go upward in the directory tree and walk again? Is there not a better solution?

Comment: @LastBerserkr do you have literally *no idea* where this directory could be?

Comment: Then instead of using `os.walk()` use `os.listdir(root_dir)` which gives you the list of all the directories in `root_dir` and you can loop over them to find that whether you have to go inside some directory or go one more up level.

Comment: @jonrsharpe not at all the user gives a directory within a directory tree and I need to copy a file in a special directory. So I have to search for this special directory which can be parent or child of the given directory.

Comment: Why don't you ask the user for more useful input? Or put that directory in a known place? Or... it seems like there are various better options, is what I'm saying.

Comment: @LastBerserkr and starting from the directory the user gives is a bit of a red herring - why not start from the root of the filesystem?

Comment: No because the user has no idea of this operation it is just like a metadata file which has to be copied in /android folder but /the location fo /android folder can varies from an app to an other. Anyway shaktimaan gave me a good solution to use os.listdir().

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I chose however I have an error when parsing the absolute path to copy the file.
I get this error, I think it is because I need absolute path, does someone know how to get an absolute path from a directory list?

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'android\\MyCustomClass.smali'
```

here is my code:

```
def copy_my_custom_class(current_dir):
    subdirs = os.listdir(current_dir)       
    for subdir in subdirs:
        if (subdir == 'android'):       
            my_custom_class_path = os.path.join(subdir, 'MyCustomClass.smali')
            shutil.copyfile('./files/MyCustomClass.smali', my_custom_class_path)    

    copy_my_custom_class(os.chdir(current_dir))
```

Comment: Here you are just joining the `subdir` path (i.e. `android`) to file. So you are trying to copy the file from your `source ` to `'android\\MyCustomClass.smali'`. You have to get the absolute path where the file actually exists. Use `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), subdir, 'MyCustomClass.smali')` if the `current_dir` is current working directory.

Comment: @shaktimaan the problem is that it is not the current working dir, so I suppose there is nothing to do, right?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. but is your issue really solved? If not then I would suggest to have a variable keeping track of absolute path for the file. And use `os.path.join(yourabspath, subdir)` if you are going inside some directory and `os.path.join(yourabspath,"..")` if you are moving up some directory. But surely you'll have to keep reack of the absolute path to access file.

Comment: No problem yes I solved my problem, it was pretty easy when I knew the existence of the os.path.dirname() method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with this code:

```
def copy_my_custom_class(current_dir):
    subdirs = os.listdir(current_dir)
    for subdir in subdirs:
        if (subdir == 'android'):   
            dest_file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, subdir, 'MyCustomClass.smali')
            shutil.copyfile('./files/MyCustomClass.smali', dest_file_path)  
            return 0

    copy_my_custom_class(os.path.dirname(current_dir))
```